# Keras: get training data from a saved model

Tags: python, keras, keras-2

Is it even possible? The model is saved by

```
ModelCheckpoint(model_path, save_best_only=True, monitor='val_acc', mode='max', save_weights_only=False)
```

Can I do something like this?

```
from keras.models import load_model
model = load_model(model_path)
X_train = model.inputs
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible. [ModelCheckpoint](https://keras.io/callbacks/#modelcheckpoint) with `save_weights_only=False` only saves the topology, the weights and the optimizer's state (if any) of the model. The training data is not saved along with the model, and `model.inputs` is just the list of the model's placeholders.

See also the [source code for ModelCheckpoint](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/callbacks.py#L358).

Comment: Thank you! I shouldn't be afraid of looking into sources myself. Btw the link you have given to ModelCheckpoint does not describe the saved model aspects. It's rather `def save(self, filepath, overwrite=True, include_optimizer=True)` in [keras/engine/network.py](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/a2d11d4724d3cf4a0b18a7fe8448723d92e1c716/keras/engine/saving.py#L26)